converting curve_fit to optimize.minimize
I have the following code which functions correctly. However, instead of using the method curve_fit, I want to perform the fitting manually using scipy.optimize.minimze on each element. Is it possible and how can we do so?
this is the data file
Here is my code
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

data = np.loadtxt('gaussian.dat')
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]

n = len(x)                          
mean = sum(x*y)/n                   
sigma = sum(y*(x-mean)**2)/n        

def gauss(x,a,x0,sigma):
    return a*np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))

popt,pcov = curve_fit(gauss,x,y,p0=[1,mean,sigma])

def get_conf_gaus(x: float,popt: np.ndarray, pcov: np.ndarray, n_boostrap:int = 100):

    params = np.random.multivariate_normal(popt, pcov, size = [n_boostrap])
    a = params[:,0]
    mu = params[:,1]
    sigma = params[:,2]

    bootstrap_y = gauss(0.2,a,mu,sigma)
    conf = np.quantile(bootstrap_y, [0.025,0.975])
    return conf

conf = get_conf_gaus(0.2, popt, pcov)
print(conf)

plt.plot(x,y,'b+:',label='data')
plt.plot(x,gauss(x,*popt),'ro:',label='fit')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Gaussian Fit vs Actual Data')
plt.xlabel('x-values')
plt.ylabel('y-values')
plt.show()


When you say that you want to do this for each element, do you mean that you want to obtain one set of parameters for each element, or do you mean that you want to fit a single set of parameters to all of the points in your data?

i would like to use the method scipy.optimize.minimize to perform the same function manually that scipy.curve_fit does automatically

Can you provide the contents of gaussian.dat to make the example reproducible?

What part of the code have you gotten stuck on?

i just added the data.

Method curve_fit
This method works well and returns alongside with optimized parameters an estimation of the covariance:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats, optimize
import numdifftools as nd

x, y = np.genfromtxt('gaussian.dat').T

def model(x, A, mu, sigma):
    law = stats.norm(loc=mu, scale=sigma)
    return A * law.pdf(x) / law.pdf(mu)

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(model, x, y)

#(array([9.85743077, 1.96427309, 1.27652119]),
# array([[ 2.92986068e-01,  6.62630072e-10, -2.52941845e-02],
#        [ 6.62630072e-10,  6.55112141e-03, -9.75743530e-11],
#        [-2.52941845e-02, -9.75743530e-11,  6.55112158e-03]]))

Method with minimize
To perform the same operation with optimize we must write the loss function for the Least Square problem. We choose to do it using wrapper:
def loss_factory(x, y):
    def wrapped(p):
        return 0.5 * np.sum(np.power(y - model(x, *p), 2))
    return wrapped

loss = loss_factory(x, y)

Then we can minimize the loss (equipped with our data as local variables):
sol = optimize.minimize(
    loss,
    x0=[1., 1., 1.],
    bounds=[(0, np.inf), (-np.inf, np.inf), (0, np.inf)]
)
#  message: CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH
#  success: True
#   status: 0
#      fun: 16.793558341382255
#        x: [ 9.857e+00  1.964e+00  1.277e+00]
#      nit: 11
#      jac: [ 1.741e-05 -6.537e-05  7.354e-05]
#     nfev: 56
#     njev: 14
# hess_inv: <3x3 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>

Which is compliant with curve_fit solution.
Now if we want to estimate the Covariance matrix, we can compute the Hessian at the solution and inverse it:
H = nd.Hessian(loss)(sol.x)
C = np.linalg.inv(H)

# array([[ 3.31906230e-01, -3.53666330e-04, -2.87276565e-02],
#       [-3.53666330e-04,  7.41295793e-03,  9.16012115e-05],
#       [-2.87276565e-02,  9.16012115e-05,  7.44036351e-03]])

Both methods agree:
xlin = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 200)

fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.scatter(x, y)
axe.plot(xlin, model(xlin, *popt))
axe.plot(xlin, model(xlin, *sol.x), "--")
axe.grid()



it does not plot

Your question was not about how to plot, but how to switch from curve_fit to minimize. Anyway I added the snippet that creates the figure in case of you need it.
